# Android assets - not all folders/files packaged in APK

Tags: android, apk, assets, filenotfoundexception

I have problem with ASSETS folder in android. I put folders and files in ASSETS, and for some folders/files I got FileNotFoundException. Then I printed all folder/file names from ASSETS folder by code, and I saw that not all folders/files are packaged into APK. Why is that happening? All files and folders have names without special characters, example: "Prevoz tereta i lica vozilima/Prevoz tereta i lica vozilima.json"? For some files/folders it works, and for some it doesn't. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found solution for my problem. Files that needed to be in ASSETS folder were created on my desktop. I created ASSETS folder in Android Studio, but when I was putting files from desktop to assets I didn't put them via Android Studio but Windows Explorer instead. I found location of assets folder and pasted files there, so I think that Android Studio didn't index some of them. Now I created 4-5 files and folders via Android Studio (right click on assets folder -> new -> file/directory), and every one of them is packaged and working all right. So I think that was the problem and the solution. I will have to create every file and folder by hand in Android Studio, then just put data in those empty files afterwards. Thank you all for help/suggestions. I'm glad that I found the solution, even if it's stupid.
I'll make this an accepted answer tomorrow, because stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do so until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow refresh your project.
If you are using Android Studio goto File>Synchronize or press 'CTRL + ALT + y'.
Make sure your assets folder is in src/main directory of your project.

Comment: It is in src/main, and I can see all files and folders from Android Studio, but still it doesn't add them to APK.

Comment: Just refresh your project and share your results

Comment: Still nothing :( I'll add picture to post, so you can see which ones don't work.

Answer (score 0):

file-invalidate and restart

tools-android-sync project with gradle files

Comment: Still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

READ IF USING IONIC AND TRANSFERRING FILES ATOM/OTHER IDE TO ANDROIDSTUDIO

There's an IDE interface issue.
What worked for me: removing and readding android as such:

`ionic cordova platform remove android`
(you might have to manually remove android folder from platforms)

`ionic cordova platform add android`

Then you can move on with generating a release file and then generating a signed apk in android studio etc.